# How to define bold, italic for fonts hosted in the cloud?

Tags: html, css, fonts, sass, styling

I am using web fonts provided like this:

```
font-family:'Sabon LT W01 Roman';
font-family:'Sabon LT W01 Italic';
```

and would like to be able to use something like this in my css:

```
font-family: 'Sabon';
font-style: italic;
```

instead of

```
font-style: 'Sabon LT W01 Italic'
```

in my css.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am aware of the possibility to define bold/italic when using @font-face and linking to fonts directly, but this is not the case. The fonts are hosted at Fonts.com so I don't think I can use @font-face and specify font files unless I host them.

This is how I have set the styles up right now:

```
%font-serif {
  font-family:'Sabon LT W01 Roman', serif;
}

%font-serif-italic {
  font-family:'Sabon LT W01 Italic', serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

which forces me to use `@extend %font-serif;` instead of

```
@extend %font-serif;
font-style: italic;
```

Comment: Sorry about the earlier fiddle, didn't import the google font. (must be a problem with jsfiddle) Regarless, something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/P8R6q/1/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle; I went for something similar -- just with the `strong` element.

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing your fonts? direct link? if so you can still use font face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Sabon';
  src: local('Sabon'), local('Sabon'), url('http://link/font.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Then you could use it:

```
#block{
    font-family: 'Sabon';
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's a javascript. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.net/jsapi/secret-api-key.js"></script>`. I thought `local(source)` applies only to system fonts? Or would fonts imported via js/css become local?